# Can we have a Priority Queue of an array of integers in java

Tags: java, priority-queue

can we define a Priority Queue of an array that compare arrays by their length?

```
    PriorityQueue<int[]> pq=new PriorityQueue<int[]>(5, (a,b) -> a.length - b.length);
    int[] a = new int[]{1,2};
    int[] b = {1,2,3};
    int[] c = new int[]{3};
    pq.add(a);
    pq.add(b);
    pq.add(c);
    while (pq.size() != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
    }
}
```

output :

[I@1c20c684
[I@1fb3ebeb
[I@548c4f57

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pq.remove()));`

Comment: but what if we want to put it in another array?

Answer (score 1):

You can, with whatever comparator you want. Your code is printing addresses of the array as output. You can use `java.util.Arrays.toString()` method.